# SSLHandshakeException with okhttp

Tags: java, okhttp, tls1.2, websphere-8, http2

My code connects to apns for push notification. Am using clevertap library from git(https://github.com/CleverTap/apns-http2). It uses okhttp for the connection. When I run code on IBM WAS 8.5.5 and am receiving SSLHandshakeException. Details below. Can you pls help me on how to address this? Am trying with Synchronous mode of sending push message. I use Java 1.7, WAS 8.5.5. Pls let me know if you need more details.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
     at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
     at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:21)
     at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.b(qc.java:465)
     at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:451)
     at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
     at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:353)
     at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.startHandshake(qc.java:800)
     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:299)
     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268)
     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
```

When I googled for the issue, it seems the issue is because of IBMJSSE2, the JSSE implementation used by Websphere, in not compatible with this solution.
The problem is that for this implementation, the cipher suite names may starts with SSL_ or TLS_ (IBM documentation), both accepted: but that is not true for OkHttp. But I could not find a work around that I can use to fix the problem.

I read that version 3.7 of the jar will fix the problem but am using 3.9.1 and still running into the same issue.

I have the certificate imported into WAS trust store. I also have TLS 1.2 in the environment.

Comment: The text representations of the ciphers are not actually used in the protocol.  The server sent a handshake failure alert, so look in the server logs.

Comment: Have you looked into installing Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html  It will add extra ciphers capabilities.

Comment: @Yan - JCE policy changes have been implemented already.

Comment: @csharpnewbie  what about security.policy file. There are settings there to disable certain ciphers. Can you run the app with ssl debug options to see more information

Comment: @Yan - Sorry for the delayed response. Not sure how I missed this response.  My java.policy already has the entry - permission java.security.AllPermission "", ""; - If thats what you are asking for. If not, can you pls explain more?

Comment: @csharpnewbie There is a java.security file in jre/lib/security that has disabledAlgorithms property.  You might be disabling that specific algorithm.

Comment: @Yan - There is no entry for jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in that file.

Comment: @csharpnewbie kind of weird that the entry is missing .. Have you tried running the app with these parameters to debug -Djavax.net.debug=all or -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose  https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https

Comment: @Yan - Yes, we already tried that, but could not get any details from it, to point to the issue. It shows about IBM JCE, and its settings. it does show com.ibm.ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2.

Comment: Could it be some firewall issue.. Have you tried connecting using openssl?  Are you connecting using hostname or ip address?

Comment: @Yan - We have added it to the firewall for allowing the traffic. We are using hostname. We needed openSSL 1.0.2 to try connecting for these urls but since we do not have that version of the openSSL, we chose this option instead.